# Missing git file hooks/post-receive.sample

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I was using git 1.7.1 on CentOs 6 server and when I run `git --bare init` on my_repo.git I checked *my_repo.git/hooks* and I could see all hooks, including **post-receive.sample**.

Now I'm using git 2.4.1 on Centos 7 server, and post-receive.sample file is missng, all other hooks are there but not the one I need.

I know I can copy the file from a previous repo and then change content as needed, but I would like to know why the **post-receive.sample** is not generated as before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, `post-receive.sample` was removed in commit [8d714b11df2b65e5f4272c1616e561930010be90](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=8d714b11df2b65e5f4272c1616e561930010be90):

```
commit 8d714b11df2b65e5f4272c1616e561930010be90
Author: Gerrit Pape <pape@smarden.org>
Date:   Tue Sep 27 11:56:53 2011 +0000

    templates/hooks--*: remove sample hooks without any functionality

    Remove the sample post-commit and post-receive hooks.  The sample
    post-commit doesn't contain any sample functionality and the comments do
    not provide more information than already found in the documentation.
    The sample post-receive hooks doesn't provide any sample functionality
    either and refers in the comments to a contrib hook that might be
    installed in different locations on different systems, which isn't that
    helpful.

    Signed-off-by: Gerrit Pape <pape@smarden.org>
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```